# Turning strings into command without using eval()

Tags: r, subset

I know that eval() may lead to codes that are hard to maintain, but I run yet again into a case where I don't know what else to use.

Below is the manual way of getting column `a` from `data` and create a new data frame.

```
data <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10)
new.data <- data.frame( a = data[ , "a"] )
```

This works fine for one column. However, in my real application, I have to extract multiple columns into multiple new data frames, and I *must* refer to the column by name (hence the title, turning column name (i.e. string) into command). How can I do that without resorting to eval(parse=text)?

Comment: why doesn't this work for your data

Comment: The manual way work, but I want to create a function that takes in the name of a column of interest and output a new data frame. Then I will loop this function through a string vectors containing the names of all the columns of interest.

Comment: Then your loop is `for(j in col_names) data.frame(a=data[,col_names[j] ])` , basically.

Comment: Ah! That's the easy part though. The bottleneck is how to make it `data.frame(col_names=data[,j])`, i.e. naming the new data frame as the column of interest as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that data frames are stored as lists, and lists can be subset with a vector of strings (if the list is named, but the column names are the names of the list elements).  So you can just do something like:

```
> mydf <- data.frame( a=1:5, b=5:1, c=11:15, d=21:25 )
> 
> mycols <- c('a','d')
> 
> mydf[ mycols ]
  a  d
1 1 21
2 2 22
3 3 23
4 4 24
5 5 25
> str(.Last.value)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ d: int  21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my question is really not at this elementary level. I can extract columns by name fine (your answer is 100% correct in this regard). What's hard is to name the column of the newly created data frame according to a passed string. In your example, `new.df <- mydf[ mycols ]` is fine, but how to name the `new.df`'s columns using `c("dog", "cat")`?

Comment: have a look at `?setNames`

Comment: @Anh, the `names` function can be used to set the names, or as @infominer mentions, the `setNames` function can also be used.

Comment: Thanks! That works. People keep saying there are always alternatives to eval(parse(, but without someone pointing out `setNames` I'd never know!